# Please tell me how to adjust the position when the video is in the background

Tags: html, css

**Outline explanation**

I set the animation as the background using HTML and CSS. I would like to make the height of the background video the same as the height of the display. In that case, I would like to center the movie in the center and want to make the width of the movie cut at the width of the display.
In other words, I want to prevent scrolling to the left and right.

Also, letters and images are placed on the movie.

**Code**

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainimage">
  <video src="video/movie.mp4" mute autoplay loop playsinline></video>
  <div class="overlay-text">Text</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
video {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.main-box {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**Supplementary information**

A detailed description of HTML and CSS is omitted.
If there is anything, I will update it from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding correctly, you want the video to be set as a full-screen background image and when resized you don't want the video to clip. One quick way to achieve this would be to add `object-fit:cover;` to your video tag. It's worth noting that `object-fit` won't work for older versions of Internet Explorer.

It's also worth remembering that because the video has to fill the space - when the browser hits certain ratios the video can get really zoomed in to maintain the `cover` of its parent

```css
video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  object-fit:cover;
  
 
}
.main-box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  
}

.mainimage{
  width:100%
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div class="mainimage">
  <video src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" mute autoplay loop playsinline></video>
  <div class="overlay-text">Text</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.
Thanks to your advice the background movie worked properly.
I would like to ask additional questions, but I am glad if you can tell me.
Elements to be displayed in overlay include two inline blocked texts and images. I want to display these in the center. I tried text-align: center; or margin: 0 auto; but it did not display well.

Comment: I’m on my phone so you will have to excuse the formatting to center align the elements you simply add  ‘display:flex;’  ‘align-items:center;’ ‘justify-content:center;’ to your ‘.mainimage’ class if you need the elements to be stacked rather than inline you can also add ‘flex-direction:column’

Comment: Thanks to your cooperation I was able to solve the problem. Thank you for lending me the power of a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

First off this is something which is relatively hard to do as many webpages involve scrolling. But I did this with an image on this website. http://www.patriotperspective.com

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>    
        #video {                   
          position: fixed;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="video">
  <video style="display:center"  src="video/movie.mp4" mute autoplay loop playsinline></video>
  <div class="overlay-text">Text</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

I assume you know what to do with Head and body. Hopefully this should work with your video but you should be able to make easy adjustments.